# Full Screen sizes

Tags: android

I Used this image sizes for fullscreen
                ldpi 240*320
                mdpi 320*480
                hdpi 480*800
               xhdpi 600*1024
               xxhdpi 768*1280

But these sizes are not fitted for note 3 mobiles.can anyone suggest for the image sizes.

Comment: what you actually need? bcoz android has multiple size available

Answer (score 0):

The screen resolutions you have listed are only a few of the screen resolutions that Android devices may actually use. Your pairing of them with different screen *densities* (ldpi, etc) is just a rule-of-thumb that comes from the Android docs.

Do you want a way of determining the device screen size programmatically, or do you just want to know the size in advance for a limited number of devices?

The Samsung Galaxy Note 3 display is, I believe, 1200(w) x 1920(h) pixels. You will lose some pixels at the bottom for the Android soft keys. If the notification bar is displayed at the top of the screen, then you will also lose some pixels at the top.

Comment: Actually Samsung Galaxy Note 3 display size is [1080(w)x1920(h)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_3).

Comment: so i can put the 1080*1920 as imagesize in xhdpi

Answer (score 0):

Try to create folder **drawable-xhdpi** or *drawable-sw1080dp* with resources what you needed in it. For more details see ["Using new size qualifiers"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers) on Android Developers.